# Regex to determine if a string is a name of a range or a cell's address

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm struggling to come up with a regular expression pattern that can help me determine if a string is a cell's address or if it is a cell's name.

Here are some examples of cell addresses:

- "E5"
- "AA55:E5"
- "DD5555:DDD55555, E5, F5:AA55"
- "$F7:$G$7"

Here are some examples of cell names:

- "bis_document_id"
- "PCR1MM_YPCVolume"
- "sheet_error7"
- "blahE5"
- "training_A1"
- "myNameIsGeorgeJR"

### Is there a regex pattern you guys can come up with that will match all of either group and none of the other?

I have been able to think of a couple of ways to determine what a string is not:

- If it has any other character than "$" or ":" in it, I know it is not a cell's name and is most likely a cell's address.
- If it has more than three consecutive numbers, it is most likely not a cell's address.
- A cell's address is extremely unlikely to have more than 2 letters preceding a number, 99.9% of the cell addresses will be in columns A to ZZ.

Alas, these three small tests can hardly prove what this string is.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe simpler: [`^(?!.*_)[\dA-Z:$, ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1vrOT7/2)

Comment: Do you need a regex pattern? Just playing around, I think you can do a simple script that just checks if the cell is a valid range. Take the cell, put it in `Range(cel.value).Select` and if it errors, it's not a range...?

Comment: Also named ranges are part of the collection `ThisWorkbook.Names`

Comment: @BruceWayne - `Range("AA55:E5").Select` and `Range("PCR1MM_YPCVolume").Select` are both valid statements (assuming that "PCR1MM_YPCVolume" is a cell/range name) so can't be used to differentiate between a range address and a range name.

Comment: Why do you need to determine whether it is a built-in name (such as `"AA55:E5"`) or a user-defined name (such as `"blahE5"`) ?

Comment: Is this a practical application, or is this for your own learning purposes? What kind of madman would make up such wild named ranges?! Interesting question.

Comment: Are you using this on a `Formula` object? A bit of context would be useful because it defines how we can use the start and end string anchors

Comment: Thank you, everyone! This is a practical application. There's a function called `GetRange(nameOrAddress as string)` that gets a range based on the string parameter. Right now the way I am checking is by trying to get the range's name via `Range(nameOrAddress).Name.Name`. If it throws an error, I know that string isn't associated with a range with a name. This, in my estimation, would be a more efficient and complete way to quickly determine what the string is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, this one's fun:

```
^\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?(?:,\s*(?:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?))*$
```

Let's break it down, because it's rather nasty. The magic subpattern, really, is this:

```
\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+
```

This little thing will match any single valid cell address, with optional absolute-value `$`s. The next bit,

```
(?::\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?
```

will match the same thing optionally (the `?` quantifier at the end), but preceded by a colon (`:`). That lets us get ranges. The next bit,

```
(?:,\s*(?:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?))*
```

matches the same thing as the first, but zero or more times (using the `*` quantifier), and preceded by a comma and optional spaces using the special `\s` token (which means "any whitespace").

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IuKe8u/2)

If we want to get really fancy (and, mind you, I have no idea whether Excel's regex engine supports this; I just wrote it for fun), we can use [recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) to accomplish the same thing:

```
^((\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)(?::(?2))?)(?:,\s*(?1))*$
```

In this case, the magic `\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+` is inside the *second* capturing group, which is used recursively by the `(?2)` token. The entire subpattern for a single address or range of them is contained within the *first* capture group, and is then used to match additional addresses or ranges in a list.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IuKe8u/3)

Comment: Great answer, just trying to clarify if OP wants it in the context of a Formula object or not.

Comment: Have you tried this in VBA? It's not working on mine.

Comment: Great answer, added `[a-zA-Z]` in order to seach case insensitive. In VBA @AER has to reference Microsoft Scripting Regular Expressions 5.5 to use regExp.

Answer (score 2):

So here's a regex for VBA which will find any cell reference irrespective where it is.

NOTE: I've assumed you're performing this on a `Formula` object and thus doesn't require being at the start or end of the string; so you can have a string with cell references and cell names and it will only pick up the cell references as below:

```
(?:\W|^)(\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7})?)(?!\w)
```

`(?:\W|^)` is at the start and ensures that there is a non-word character before it or the start of the string (remove `|^` if it there is always a `=` at the start as in `Formula` objects) --- VBA I found out regrettably does not have a functioning negative lookbehind)

`(\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7})?)` finds the actual cell reference and is broken down below:

- `\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}` matches to one to three capital letters (as applicable to Excel's possible current ranges;
- `(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7})?` is the same as above except it adds the option of a second cell reference after a column `?` makes it optional.

`(?!\w)` is a negative look forward and says that the character after it must not be a word character (presumably in functions the only things you can have around a cell references are parentheses and operators).

I wrote a VBA function in Excel and it returned the following with the above RegEx:

[image: RegEx Output]

NB: It doesn't pick up obviously if the characters are in the right order as the reference `$AZO113:A4` is returned despite it being impossible.

Comment: Sorry for the poor timing of clarification and context on my part. This is not on a Formula object. The strings that get passed into this `GetRange(nameOrAddress)` look like the examples I provided.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions I had to modify a regex so it works for me. my version only support non-named ranges.

```
((?![\=,\(\);])(\w+!)|('.+'!))?((\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7})?)|(\$?[A-Z]{1,3}(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?)))
```

It will capture ranges in all of the following situations

```
=FUNCTION(F:F)
=FUNCTION($B22,G$5)
=SUM($F$10:$F$11)
=$J10-$K10
=SUMMARY!D4
```

I created the following function for RegEx. but first tick the reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" from Tools>References

```
Function RegExp(ByVal sText As String, ByVal sPattern, Optional bGlobal As Boolean = True, Optional bIgnoreCase As Boolean = False, Optional bArray As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Dim objRegex As New RegExp
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection
    Dim Match As Match
    Dim i As Integer
    objRegex.IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
    objRegex.Global = bGlobal
    objRegex.Pattern = sPattern
    If objRegex.test(sText) Then
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(sText)
        If Matches.count <> 0 Then
            If bArray Then ' if we want to return array instead of MatchCollection
                ReDim aMatches(Matches.count - 1) As Variant
                For Each Match In Matches
                    aMatches(i) = Match.value
                    i = i + 1
                Next
                RegExp = aMatches
            Else
                Set RegExp = Matches
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```